# Write data retrieved from for loop

Tags: python

What is the best way to write data retrieved from for loop?

```
L = ['abc','def','ghi']

for e in L:
    with open ('outfile.txt','w') as outfile:
        print (e, file=outfile)


##But the outfile.txt contains only:
##ghi
##
##        
##I have to write all the elements:
##abc
##def
##ghi
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You re-open the file for writing each loop iteration, which *clears* the file each time.

Move the file opening **out** of the loop:

```
L = ['abc','def','ghi']

with open('outfile.txt', 'w') as outfile:
    for e in L:
        print (e, file=outfile)
```

Opening a file in `w` mode explicitly truncates it (removes all data). Quoting the [`open()` function documentation](http://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#open):

> Other common values are `'w'` for writing (truncating the file if it already exists) [...]

If you **have** to open a file for each iteration, **at the very least** open the file for appending instead, using `'a'`:

```
L = ['abc','def','ghi']

for e in L:
    with open('outfile.txt', 'a') as outfile:
        print (e, file=outfile)
```

Answer (score 4):

This is how:

```
L = ['abc', 'def', 'ghi']    
with open('outfile.txt', 'w') as outfile:
    for e in L:
        # You could also do `outfile.write(e)`
        print(e, file=outfile)
```

In the end, the file will look like this:

```
abc
def
ghi
```

Your current method is opening the file in write mode **with each iteration** of the for-loop.  This means that its contents keep getting overwritten.

Remember that each and every time you open a file in write mode, all of its contents are cleared.